# $\frac{n!}{k!}$, sum of e, direct comparison test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

how do i proof that 
$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}$ converges, that the sum is < $\frac{1}{n}$

and that 0 < $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{n*(n!)}$? 
given that the first sum is e.

I tried out a few things and it looks very similar but i cant come up with a good proof.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe start with the observation that if $k=n+1$, then $\frac{n!}{k!}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n!}{n!(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n+1}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $n$ is a positive integer,

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}
    & = \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n!}{(n+2)!}+\frac{n!}{(n+3)!}+\cdots \\
    & = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots \\
    & < \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)(n+1)}+\cdots \\
\end{align}

Can you take it from there?

Comment: so i proof that the product of (n+k) k=1 to n < (n+1)^n ?

Comment: which leads to $\frac{n!}{k!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)^n}$
thank you, could i get a hint for the second part?

Comment: It's actually $\frac{n!}{k!} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^k}$.  It's a straight geometric series with the desired sum.

Comment: oh, ok, thank you, i think i made a mistake at the second part, but can´t see it.

$e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$
$e - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{n=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} $ => $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!} ??$

Comment: its $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ ofc